# psql cast parse fails even when the error returns from a gorm method

Tags: postgresql, go, error-handling, go-gorm

I have following code in my project in order to have better database error handling:

```
package repository

import (
    "errors"

    "github.com/lib/pq"
    "github.com/sirupsen/logrus"
    "gorm.io/gorm"
)

var (
    // ErrRecordNotFound indicates that specified record was not found.
    ErrRecordNotFound = errors.New("record not found")
    // ErrDuplicateEntry indicates that duplicate entry for this key exists.
    ErrDuplicateEntry = errors.New("record already exists")
)

// ParseError tries to catch gorm or sql driver error and return
// wrapped appropriate model error.
func ParseError(err error) error {
    switch {
    case err == nil:
        return nil
    case errors.Is(err, gorm.ErrRecordNotFound):
        return ErrRecordNotFound
    case errors.Is(err, gorm.ErrDuplicatedKey):
        return ErrDuplicateEntry
    default:
        if psqlErr, ok := err.(*pq.Error); ok && psqlErr.Code.Name() == "unique_violation" {
            logrus.Error("error code is 23505")
            logrus.Errorf("casting psqlErr: %v", psqlErr)
            logrus.Errorf("casting psqlErr code: %s", psqlErr.Code)
            logrus.Errorf("casting psqlErr code name: %s", psqlErr.Code.Name())

            return ErrDuplicateEntry
        }

        logrus.Errorf("err: %v", err)
        logrus.Errorf("err string: %s", err.Error())

        return err
    }
}
```

But as I checked, the `ok` in `psqlErr, ok := err.(*pq.Error)` turns to be false and the only logs I get is following lines which are printed right before `return err`:

```
time="2023-07-03T13:49:32Z" level=error msg="err: ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint \"name_department_id_idx\" (SQLSTATE 23505)"
time="2023-07-03T13:49:32Z" level=error msg="err string: ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint \"name_department_id_idx\" (SQLSTATE 23505)"
```

As you can see, this error is exactly what I am trying to catch, but how can't I cast it to a `*pq.Error`?

**Edit 1: **

I have also tried `errors.As(err, &psqlErr)` which did not help.

**Edit 2:**
I tried checking type of `err` using `log.Printf("error type=%T\n", err)` as @mkopriva suggested. It turned to be `*pgconn.PgError`. I changed my code as follows:

```
    if psqlErr, ok := err.(*pgconn.PgError); ok && psqlErr.Code == "23505" {
        return ErrDuplicateEntry
    }
```

But this also did not work.

Comment: If the type assertion doesn't match `*pq.Error` then the error's type isn't `*pq.Error` (at least not the same version as the one you've imported). The logs you've shown do not in the slightest prove that `err` is `*pq.Error`. Instead try `log.Printf("error type=%T\n", err)` to print the error's actual type. And if that statement truly logs `error type=*pq.Error` then that means that the `lib/pq` version that you are importing is different from the version that `gorm` is returning the error from.

Comment: Note that the expression `err.(*pq.Error)` is a [type assertion](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Type_assertions), it is not a "type cast". A type assertion checks whether the dynamic type of an interface value is identical to the specified type. Or, if the specified type is an interface type, then the type assertion checks if the dynamic type implements that specified interface. This is very different from the concept of type casting/conversion. A type assertion basically ask the runtime if `X` is `Y`, a type cast, on the other hand, asks the runtime _to turn_ `X` _into_ `Y`.

Comment: You need to make sure that the version of the `pgconn` package that you are importing in that file is the same as the version of the `pgconn` package that `gorm` uses to return the error.

Comment: You're either using `github.com/jackc/pgconn` and `gorm` is using `github.com/jackc/pgx/pgconn` (or the other way around); Or both you and `gorm` are importing `github.com/jackc/pgx/pgconn` but a different version of `github.com/jackc/pgx` (latest version is `v5` so maybe one of you is on `v4`, it happens a lot).